# ES6 jsdom cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, es6-modules, jsdom

I'm trying to setup unit testing with Mocha while using jsDOM to simulate the virtualDom for my ES6; but I keep getting errors with the recent

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

Here's my main.js setup

```js
    const url = 'https://localhost/demo.json';
    const source = document.getElementById('row-template').innerHTML;
    const contentLoop = document.getElementById('feedback-loop');
    const searchForm = document.getElementById('searchForm');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const ratingEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.ratings__button');
    const lengthContainer = document.querySelector('.length');
```

and my test file, simply includes this main.js file

The error occurs on every line that has the `.innerHTML` method

`const main = require('../src/js/main');`

While mocha runs with this dom.js file https://gist.github.com/ChidinmaKO/cd5a35624285c07e61a5373c5c8ff3ea

Please help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have this line:

```
document.getElementById('row-template').innerHTML;
```

And this error:

> cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

"Cannot read property `innerHTML`" is referring to the `.innerHTML` call. It's saying that the left part of the property access,  `document.getElementById('row-template')` is `null`. The reason it's null is because `document.getElementById('row-template')` is not finding an HTML element in the document with that ID.

Make sure the ID is actually present in the DOM. A very common mistake is running your code in a script block that's executing before the entire HTML document is present (for example, if your script element is in the `<head/>` of the HTML). Placing the code at the bottom of the body will make sure that the rest of the HTML actually exists before the code runs.

If this is occurring within your test, you'll have to make sure the DOM structure expected by the code is arranged by the test's setup.